# how to chop off semicolon, apostrophe and comma from a string

Tags: asp.net

I have a aspx form and a multiline textbox. I am sending the textbox value to Oracle table and Oracle does not like apostrophe and semicolon. So can you please tell me how to exclude apostrophe and semicolon from a string? i am doing like this.

```
     using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                    connection.Open();

                    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Name of procedure or function to be executed
                    command.CommandText = "PROC_SENDREQUISITION";

                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ReqID", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = preqID;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_reqDate", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = preqDate;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_requester", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = prequester;
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_remarks", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = premarks;


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Comment: Show us some of the code you are using to do this. Are your queries parameterized?

Comment: Oracle is perfectly able to handle such characters, as soon as it is properly encoded. I bet you are not using parameters on your OracleCommand object?

Comment: I can't figure out anything from the question asked and code pasted.

Comment: Please include actual error message you're getting

Comment: Amin what you didnt understand..its a simple english

Answer (score 1):

Use **parameters** in your query.

Right now you are probably concatenating strings, which leads to **Sql Injection**.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.aspx):

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE ?";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = "a";
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: please see my edited question..i am getting error when my textfield has apostrophe. what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

string.replace(";", "") should do the trick, but it sounds like you have SQL Injection issues. So I would recommend reading up on SQL injection, and addressing that instead of removing semi colons and apostrophes.

Comment: to quote the OP "So can you please tell me how to exclude apostrophe and semicolon from a string", I answered his question, but as you can see I recommended he address any SQL injection issues instead of replace characters.